# mysql query get 1st specific day between 2 dates

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get the first Sunday between 2 dates?
    i have only 2 fields in myTable (dt_from and dt_to)

```
dt_from = '2016-08-6';
dt_to = '2016-08-19';

SELECT firstsunday FROM myTable BETWEEN dt_from AND dt_to;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about getting the first Sunday just after from date itself?

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(A.date_from, INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(A.date_from)) DAY) from myTable as A;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fce5

If Sunday isn't between the dates:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(A.date_from, INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(A.date_from)) DAY) as firstsunday from myTable as A where DATE_ADD(A.date_from, INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(A.date_from)) DAY) between A.date_from and A.date_to;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83d0f0/4

A little bit shorter:

```
SELECT firstsunday from (SELECT A.date_from, A.date_to, DATE_ADD(A.date_from, INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(A.date_from)) DAY) as firstsunday from myTable as A) as B where B.firstsunday between B.date_from and B.date_to;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6adab3/1

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated the answer. But I don't know how to shorten it, yet.

Comment: What a creative solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT dt, DAYNAME(dt) as day 
FROM myTable WHERE dt BETWEEN date1 AND date2
ORDER BY dt
WHERE day = "Sunday"
LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: hi sir, thnx for your speed response.. i edited my post sir to replicate my current table setup. ( i dont have dt fields)

Answer (score 0):

assume you only need to sue the db to get the date range so you dont want any king of query.

```
<?php

echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime('next Sunday', strtotime('2016-08-6')));
```

you can add some validation to make sure its before your end date

Comment: hi sir, thnx for your reply,, but i want to get it directly from a query